# Sharepoint Javascript Query Fails in Google Chrome - 404 Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, sharepoint

I'm using a query to retreive sharepoint items and the query work in IE but it fails in google chrome, could you please help me to understand what is wrong with google chrome.

Error when i debug : **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)**

My code :

```
function () {  

       var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId; 
       var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")"; 
       var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
       $.ajax({
           url: requestUri,
           contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
           headers: requestHeaders,
           success: onSuccess,
       });

       function onSuccess(data, request) {
           var loginName = data.d.LoginName;
           LOGIN = loginName; 

           $http({ 
               method: 'GET',
               url: "http://spserver/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listName+"')/items?$filter=who eq '" + LOGIN + "'",
               headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
           }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               $scope.customers = data.d.results;
           }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

           });
       };
   }
```

Update : 
[he convert the (') to %27](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpOck.png)

Comment: Do you know which of the two requests is failing? That is, either the `$.ajax` call or the `$http` call in your code?

Comment: it is the  "$http" request that fails 
"who" is a column that i created in the list

Comment: Does it work if you navigate to the URL in Chrome, plugging in the appropriate values for `listName` and `LOGIN`? `http://spserver/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listName')/items?$filter=who eq 'LOGIN'`

Comment: Yes i get an xml file

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure the url is accurate? You could try building the URL from the page context as you did with the ajax request, e.g. `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/...`?

Comment: i tried it but i get the same Error what i understand from the debug is that he convert the ( ' ) to %27 because i tried to put the url as a complet string and it's working fine so i think it's only because he convert  (?$filter=who eq ') to (?$filter=who%20eq%20%27)

Comment: I don't believe that's the problem. You should be able to navigate to `http://spserver/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listName')/items?‌​$filter=who%20eq%20%27LOGIN%27` and the browser will interpret it the same as `http://spserver/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listName')/items?‌​$filter=who eq 'LOGIN'`

Comment: i tried the query without the filter and it shows all the results 
somthing is going on with the filter line

Answer (score 0):

The 'who' column is a calculated sharepoint columns and everytime a user create an item sharepoint add his login in this column, the problem was he add "i:0#.w|corp\spdev" instead of "corp\spdev"
somehow it's working in IE even with the "i:0#.w|" but in Google Chrome he don't accept it, so i change this columns with a split to keep only the login name without the "i:0#.w|" and it's working in IE & Google Chrome.